# Redis cache memory usage

Tags: cache, memory, redis

I’m runnung a few Craft sites with Redis cache enabled. It works fine. Except that Craft only uses around 3mb of Redis memory, with peaks up to 5, while there’s 128mb available.

Is there a way to set the amount of memory Craft can use? I couldn’t find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention if it's Crat 2 or Craft 3, but I'm not seeing anything in either codebase where Craft (or Yii) would limit the amount of memory available in its caching classes.

Comment: I'm using Craft 3. It seems that after ± 1,5 week the memory usage goes up. I think it just needed some time... Thanks for the help!